# Anybody updates "Status Comments" in the list, it must trigger an email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Here is the scenario.

Stage 1: Item is created -> Email sent to admins -> If Status = Investigating -> Send email to Assigned to and Created by -> Go to Stage 2.

Stage 2: If Status Comments modified either by "created by" or "assigned to," an email should be triggered. This works fine for one instance of comments added.

I want this step to be repeated until there is another Status change.

Comment: Do you have the checkbox ticked for running on updates on the stage 2 workflow?

Comment: Yes, checkbox is ticked.